# Defining a case class in zeppelin fails

Tags: scala, apache-zeppelin, case-class

I am using zeppelin embedded in another application. The zeppelin version is 0.6.1-SNAPSHOT. Defining the below case class I get an error

```
case class GenRandInt(lb : Int, ub : Int)
{
 val rnd = new scala.util.Random
 def next() : Int = { lb + rnd.nextInt(ub) }
}

defined class GenRandInt 
<console>:40: error: not found: value lb
               def next() : Int = { lb + rnd.nextInt(ub) }
```

The code executes successfully in an IDE. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Hi @Andy Dufresne. Could you add stacktrace (error logs) / your env (OS, Java, and so on.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was due to indentation.

[image]

#### Details

scala> :paste
    // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

```
case class GenRandInt(lb : Int, ub : Int)
{
 val rnd = new scala.util.Random
 def next(): Int = { lb + rnd.nextInt(ub) }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class GenRandInt

scala>
```

In scala, we can define case classes using that indentation. So I think it's the problem of spark interpreter in zepplin or maybe spark itself. (tested on scala 2.10.6, zeppelin 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT built with scala 2.10.6)

Comment: Thanks for the test on 0.7. Did you test on 0.6 version of zeppelin and found the indentation problem or are you suspecting that the problem could be due to indentation?

Comment: I tested it on also 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2 bin-all. Have u still problem after fixing that indentation? I am not sure what version of commit you are using, but i got the same message even in 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (current master) so i think it's not a problem of your snapshot version.

Comment: Yes. It worked once I moved the { bracket next to the case class line instead of being at the new line. It sounds very strange for the language like scala to have this restriction. It must be the scala interpreter in zeppelin as you mentioned.

Comment: The problem is not the indentation per se, the problem is the :paste mode. When you put the { in the next line then the first sentence "case class ..." is sent to the interpreter... and finish there. The next { is interpreted as a independent block of code and not as part of the case class.

Comment: Zeppelin rewrite its spark interpreter in 0.8. You can try that via zeppelin master or 0.8 (will be released soon) via set zeppelin.spark.useNew as true in its interpreter setting.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is Zeppelin don't have the :paste mode so the first line:

`case class GenRandInt(lb : Int, ub : Int)`

... is sent to the interpreter, and then the next block:

`{
 val rnd = new scala.util.Random
 def next() : Int = { lb + rnd.nextInt(ub) }
}`

... is interpreted as an independent block of code.

When you put the `{` in the same line as the case class, then Zeppelin understands the next lines are part of the previous block of code (until you close the `}`).

One trick I saw related with this issue is to put two sentences on the same line separated by ; (for example for companion objects), something like:

`case class XXX () {
 ...
}; object XXX () {
...
}`